# Need to stop an app that was launched via Context.startActivity();

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My app launches an app to display images selected by the user, but it needs to be able to terminate the displayer app on certain conditions. Here's what I have so far:

```
Uri attachmentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/" + filename));

attachmentViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
attachmentViewIntent.setDataAndType(attachmentUri, contentType);

attachmentViewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

try {
    mContext.startActivity(attachmentViewIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

The images get displayed just fine, but I don't see how to kill the display app. I tried

```
        mContext.stopService(attachmentViewIntent);
```

but that had no effect (I'm not sure I want to stop the service anyway, just the displayer). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once started the new activity, it will be up to the user to stop it (or less) and you have no control on how and when it will happen.

Calling `Context.stopService(Intent)` is used to stop a working `Service`, hence you have no effect because you started an `Activity` instead.

**EDIT:**
If you are not familiar with the concept of task in Android you should absolutely take a look at the docs:

- [Navigation between apps](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#between-apps)
- [Tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: Why is this true that I have no control over the life of the app I launched? Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Because the `Intent` you use to start a new `Activity` is a plain message with a "command" (actually an action and the needed data), not an handle for the new `Activity`. Actually to me is counter-intuitive that you want to kill the new `Activity` from the calling one instead. I think you should better explain what you want to achieve. Maybe there is another way to do it.

Comment: I want to have the image display for a fixed amount of time, say, 10 seconds, and then disappear. Kind of like what Snapchat does.

Comment: I think you should implement the "viewer" `Activity` your own and use it to show the image of your choice. You can then use a timer to invoke `finish()` on such `Activity` and come back to the main one.

Comment: Hmmm...that's a thought. I think that can be easily done. Thanks!